24.10 Fails to connect to JBL speaker every time it boots up
It's frustrating that after upgrading to 24.10, it can't connect to my JBL speaker even manually. I have to unpair and repair every time the system boots up. All other bluetooth devices are OK.

same for my oneplus buds

Same for me on Kubuntu 24.10 with Accentum headset after upgrade from 24.04.

It seems to be a kernel bug. I was having a similar issue with a Sennheiser Accentum headset after upgrading from Kubuntu 24.04 to 24.10. I asked on the Kubuntu sub on reddit and was kindly given this link:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2084337
